# How do I add a class to a React Native App?

Tags: react-native

I add a class just like in React.js but when the app runs it says the class doesn't exist.  The new class I am adding can be in the same folder as index.ios.js and it still doesn't find it.
**My index.ios.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Test from './Test.jsx';

export default class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Test />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);

**My new class:**
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is Test.</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

}
module.exports = Test;
```

When I run the app it compiles but in the simulator it says that class can't be found.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually no problems with your code, only you had export 2 times. Just remove `module.exports = Test;` and try again. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

These didn't solve it but I figure out what it was:

My files had the '.jsx' extension instead of '.js'

My app worked once I changed them to '.js'.